# probleme with connect-multiparty temporary directory

Tags: node.js

I am using 'connect-multiparty' to upload images to NodeJS. My problem is that the uploaded images are temporarily saved in a directory there is a way to make them saved without being deleted

```
var multipartMiddleware = multipart(' uploadDir: './upload' ')
app.post('/notes',multipartMiddleware,function(req,res) {
```

Comment: Did you tried to copy the image in the controller code to the final destination where you want it to persist?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code....

Comment: No i didn't do that, could you tell me how and thank you